# MongoDB: query result match any value in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have some documents :

```
{

    "storeID" : "715R",
    "sensorID" : [ 
        "0BBA", 
        "0BB9"
    ]
}
{

    "storeID" : "312R",
    "sensorID" : [  
        "0BBB"
    ]
}
```

I want to get result of `sensorID` which `sotreID` match any value in `storeIDarray` like `['715R','312R','789R']`

in this case I want get result : a `sensorID` array :   `[ "0BBA", "0BB9","0BBB"]`

what should I do? thanks.

Comment: [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) and then either use a projection or [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Treating peers as a coding service is generally not taken too well. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.

Comment: In a document whose storeID matches with the value we are passing as a response you want sensorID's of this storeID .Am I right????

Comment: You can use `distinct` if it suit your needs. `db.collection_name.distinct("sensorID", {storeID: {$in: ['715R','312R','789R'] }})`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take a look at the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator in MongoDB. 
Use it with a find, then, to make your request faster, you can use the [`lean`](http://blog.sandromartis.com/2016/05/08/mongoose-lean/) method : with it, mongoDB will return JS objects and not Mongoose model/objects.

```
YourModel.find({storeID: {$in: storeIDarray }}).lean().exec(yourCallback);
```

Then, you can use the `reduce` method on the resulting array :

```
yourResult.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el.sensorID), []);
```

Hope it helps, 
Best regards