# Query MongoDB to find array that contains elements from another array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

For my `users` table, each user has an `emails<Array>` property allowing them to associate multiple emails with their accounts. I want to make sure this is still unique so wether they're creating a new account or updating existing I need to query the DB to identify if that email address exists.

I know I can use `users.find({ emails: email })` and could loop over that to identify, then check the `_id` (on update) to ensure everything but that puts me in a loop outside the query.

I'm curious if there's a method I'm not seeing for querying to identify if *any* emails  being submitted match any emails from across the table in the db?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: query result match any value in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111398/mongodb-query-result-match-any-value-in-array)

Comment: Note: to alleviate any confusion about this being a duplicate, the `$in` operator works on array fields as well as non-array fields. To provide a specific answer, the query `users.find({emails: {$in: [email]}})` should do the trick.